# BASH arguments in functions

Tags: bash

Is it possible to create a script that will prompt a user to enter a number that will then programmatically be used for the number of arguments in a function/method? For example:

```
echo "Enter Number of arguments: "
read numOfArguments
```

Once a number is entered, this will stand for the number of parameters in a function. So if I enter 5, there should be 5 expected parameters within that method once called:

```
sampleMethod(){
...Takes 5 Parameters and actual code is here
}
sampleMethod ActualArgumentsfromPrompt
```

If this is possible can someone provide an example of how this is done? I am doing this because I would like to create a script that will parse through a log file but I need to pull specific items from the log that are set up similar to this: `(0010,0020)`. The information I need will not always be a fixed number of items so that's why I would like to generate a prompt for a number of arguments.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Bash functions don't have a fixed number of arguments. You can just put a loop in the function that processes all the arguments.

Comment: If you want to check that the expected number of arguments are passed, you can use `if [ $# -eq $numOfArguments ]`

Comment: Ok sorry it doesnt make sense, thats why I asked if such a thing was possible.

Comment: Assuming @Barmar's answer isn't the answer you were looking for can you more fully explain what you are trying to do here? That is what your goal is?

Comment: @Barmar would it be possible for you to provide a sample of a loop that would echo all arguments in a sample function? That would be a good example I can look into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash functions don't "expect" any number of arguments -- as you can see from the syntax, there's no list of parameter variables after the function name. They process arguments the same way the main shell does, by accessing them as `$1`, `$2`, etc. If you need to know how many arguments were passed, you can use `$#`.

To loop through all arguments, the common idiom is to process `$1`, then use `shift` to shift the argument list down.

```
sampleMethod() {
    if [ $# -ne $numOfArguments ]
    then echo Wrong number of arguments -$numOfArguments expected, $# provided >&2
         return
    fi
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        arg=$1
        echo "$arg"
        shift
    done
}
```